# Deploy ZF2 site to shared host

Tags: zend-framework2

When you deploy a Zend Framework website to a shared host, you usually cannot change the DocumentRoot to point at the public/ folder of the website. As a result the URL to the website is now http://www.example.com/public/. This doesn't look very professional, so I'd like to remove it. Up to now I have used ZF1 and Rob Allen kindly provides a method for doing this on his blog http://akrabat.com/zend-framework/zend-framework-on-a-shared-host/ . I have tried to modify this for ZF2. He proposes placing an index.php file in the root with the line:

`include 'public/index.php';`

After doing this, http://www.example.com opens the index page OK but the CSS links are broken. Rob adds a controller plugin to reset the baseUrl to /public to deal with public facing CSS and image files etc. To do this in ZF2 I found an item from Matthew Weier O' Phinney http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/Setting-the-base-url-in-ZF2-MVC-td3946284.html where he describes how to set the baseUrl. Based on his code I added this to modules/Application/Module.php

```
class Module {
    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e) {
        $config          = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('config');
        $router          = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('router');        
        $router->setBaseUrl($config['base_url']);
    }
}
```

The base_url key is set in  modules/Application/configs/module.config.php:

`'base_url' => '/public'`

I was able to dump the router object and confirm that the base_url was being set correctly at this stage. Unfortunately, now http://www.example.com no longer opens the index page and gives a 404 routing error.

Is anyone able to tell me what I am doing wrong or point me in the right direction for running a ZF2 site in a shared hosted environment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you using the skeleton app?

that seems a little over the top, surely it's lot simpler than that.

move everything from public to the root

change index.php

```
<?php
/**
 * This makes our life easier when dealing with paths. Everything is relative
 * to the application root now.
 */
//chdir(dirname(__DIR__));
chdir(__DIR__);

// Setup autoloading
require 'init_autoloader.php';

// Run the application!
Zend\Mvc\Application::init(require 'config/application.config.php')->run();
```

Simples.

If you are running an application like this you may want to block direct access to some of the Zend Framework folders using htaccess etc

Comment: Yes I am using the skeleton app. I have lots of ZF1 sites that are hosted this way so I assumed that this would not be a problem with ZF2. I guess I am a little uncomfortable with losing the Public directory but I can't really say why.

Comment: it's the easiest way if you can't move your ZF out of the document root

Comment: do you not have access to the folder above, usually even with shared hosting you can access the level below, with public_html, or htdocs containing all your web viewable files..if that is so then even better you can just move all your ZF files a level below

Comment: I'm testing it out as we speak. I have it running on a local server and I have re-directed the virtual host to the document root rather than /public to simulate the hosted environment. I have moved everything in the public folder into the root. The site runs but something is throwing a a weird error that I need to track down. I am not sure if it is directly related to the new arrangement or not but the Service manager is complaining that it cannot fetch or create an instance of baseurl. I am trying to track it down but it seems to be an Ajax call and it is making it harder to identify

Comment: it is probablt something else, if you paste the error maybe I can help

Comment: You are right. It was me thrashing around trying to get it working and leaving old code behind. I have tidied up and your solution is working so thanks for all your help.