# Zend Framework 2 deployment problems

Tags: php, .htaccess, zend-framework, zend-framework2, web-hosting

I created a small web application (from a zend skeleton application) able to manage registration and login operations.
I've used xampp to develop and test my application locally where everything works fine. 
I uploaded application files online on free hosting server 'byehost.com', following indications given in this discussion:

[Deploy ZF2 site to shared host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15250542/deploy-zf2-site-to-shared-host)

When I access the homepage of my application everything works fine, but if navigation ends on a page where a form is included I get this error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Authorization\Form\LoginForm' not found in /home/vol7_6/byethost8.com/b8_15007573/htdocs/module/Authorization/src/Authorization/Controller/LoginController.php on line 23

Forms class are included in a folder called "Form" at path *module\Authorization\src\Authorization\Form*, where 'authorization' is the name chosen for the module.

Is it necessary to add specific instructions to .htacces file, or does the problem depends on something else?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically these sorts of problems are caused by developing on a case-insensitive file system (Windows). The path you've given looks correct, so check that the filename of your form class is indeed `LoginForm.php` (case sensitive).

Comment: You're right, the filename was loginform.php. Renaming it 'LoginForm.php', everything works fine! Thanks a lot Tim!